# Descriptografar Procedures e Funções no SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Preciso descriptografar algumas rotinas que estão usando "`WITH ENCRYPTION`" e gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma pelo próprio SQL Server, sem precisar utilizar ferramentas de terceiros, que faça isso.

Comment: Depois de criptografado, não há nenhuma maneira direta no SQL Server para descriptografar o procedimento. Talvez seja necessário pesquisar na web para encontrar ferramentas de terceiros para descriptografá-las. Portanto, mantenha o código-fonte do objeto em um controle de origem antes de executar a opção CREATE object script with encrypt.

Comment: Veja o assunto http://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/sql-server/encrypting-stored-procedure

Comment: Olá Marconcilio, Não criei, porém preciso dar manutenção em muitas, e todas as functions, Views e Procedures estão dessa forma e até tentei utilizar o Redgate SQL mas era trial e agora não consigo mais usa-lo.

Comment: Depois e muito pesquisar, encontrei alguém que já deve ter passado pelo mesmo e resolveu compartilhar. Segue o link https://www.dirceuresende.com/blog/sql-server-como-recuperar-o-codigo-fonte-de-um-objeto-criptografado-with-encryption/

Comment: Somente para confirmar, o conteúdo do link atende perfeitamente, não exibe como resultado apenas como mensagem, mas funcionou.